# How do I put input type="text" on the Image using css and html

Tags: html, css, textinput

I do not want to know How to use image as an input text.
I want to know How do I put the text input on the Image

login.html

```
<div id = "background">
   <img class="stretch" alt="" src="C:\Users\joseph\Documents\GitHub\Spring2014\CMP342\MainProject\WebContent\WEB-INF\img\login.png">
      <div class = "text">
          <input type="text" >
          <input type="text" >
      </div>
</div>
```

login.css

```
#background{
  margin-left:30%;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
.stretch{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.text{

}
```

What am I trying to do now is imitating the Google "Sign in" page

Comment: i noticed you didn't close your input tags

Comment: I have Image and 'input text' should be on the image

Comment: if you want to use the linked image as a background with the text inputs on top, you're going to need to make the linked image a background image for the background div.  you don't need an '<img>' tag.

Comment: I am asking you how to fix the position

Comment: from what i see google doesnt have an image behind the signin form. Could you post a link to what you are trying to imitate.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options

1. Set background image for the #backkground. Use margin, padding, or other background css for positioning. This option won't need any img tag.
2. Use position: relative on the #background, and position: absolute on the .text. Use left, top, right, bottom css on #text for any kind of positioning you want.

I would recommend going with the 1st option. But if you feel the need to keep the img tag for some reasons, then the second option is good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to close your text input tags.  Also try this.

CSS:

```
#background {
    margin-left: 30%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url(C:\Users\joseph\Documents\GitHub\Spring2014\CMP342\MainProject\WebContent\WEB-INF\img\login.png);
    background-size: contain;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "background">
 <div class = "text">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Use CSS to position your text inputs where you'd like inside the div.